# BeautfilSoup Python , get all text between two Tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to get the text between two tags while there are other tags in between?

**For example:**

```
<ul>
  <span class = one      > Text that I want </span>
  <span class = two      > Text that I want </span>
  <li class = ....   > Text that I want </li>
</ul>
```

So. I simply want any string between the Tags `<ul>` and `</ul>`

Comment: what do u mean by "any text " ?

Comment: Text that would be displayed on the site , maybe I should've said strings

Comment: @kogoromori Use `soup.findAll(text=True)` to get all text.

Comment: Try this `print(soup.select_one('ul').text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
In [31]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [32]: x = """<ul>
    ...:   <span class = one      > 1Text that I want </span>
    ...:   <span class = two      > 2Text that I want </span>
    ...:   <li class = ....   > 3Text that I want </li>
    ...: </ul>"""

In [33]: soup = BeautifulSoup(x)

In [34]: for li in soup.findAll('ul'):
    ...:     print(li.text)
    ...:

 1Text that I want
 2Text that I want
 3Text that I want


In [35]:
```